# What is best practice for hiding a password that gets sent through a rest call to service running on an EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, encryption, amazon-ec2, password-protection

Is there a good practice for hiding a password that gets sent through a rest call to service running on an EC2.

One method I have seen is storing the password in a properties file on the EC2 and then adding a line like this into the JSON payload in the rest call

```
"database.password": "${file:/var/run/secret.properties:PASSWORD}"
```

This isn't entirely secure, anyone that can gain access to the EC2 can get the password as it is store in plain text in a folder.

I can't find much about best practices online I have had a look around.

Answer (score 1):

You may use AWS:

1. Secret Manager (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html)
2. Parameter Store (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html)

In both, you may save your secrets securely and possibly encrypted and can be accessed via API, CLI or SDK whenever you need. Also you can use IAM role based permissions to allow access to manage and access the secrets in a granular level.